# Checking for update: how it works?

Tags: windows-update

Whats transactions are running behind a windows update check?

When we try to update windows operating system, the first step will be checking for updates and after the checking is over it starts downloading patches and install it.

My question is what is actually happening in a PC during the "checking for update" stage of windows update process.

It will be great If someone can give me a precise answer. Suggeations are also acceptable....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the process Windows update connects your computer to the Windows update website. Certain software scans your OS and find whether your computer needed an update or not. If needed, then it provides the update file to your computer to download.

Take a look at this document [Windows Update Explained - Download Center - Microsoft](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fa%2F9%2F4%2Fa94af289-a798-4143-a3f8-77004f7c2fd3%2FWindows%2520Update%2520Explained.docx&ei=P_iUVfn3MoHlUuLuh-gB&usg=AFQjCNHeRlY5qoISxRJbfBxSq-_lEtbJaw&sig2=fihmVNZZ-K3d_vKChsT6UA&bvm=bv.96952980,d.ZGU&cad=rja):

> **Checking for updates**
>
> The Windows Update client on your PC checks the
>   Windows Update server at Microsoft for the availability of new updates
>   at random intervals, every 17 to 22 hours.
>
> The randomization ensures
>   that the Windows Update server is not overloaded with requests for
>   updates all at the same time. The client is very efficient in checking
>   for new updates and searches only for updates that have been added
>   since the last time updates were searched, allowing it to find updates
>   quickly and efficiently.
>
> **When checking for updates, the Windows
>   Update client evaluates whether the update is appropriate for your
>   computer using guidelines defined by the publisher of the update, for
>   example, Microsoft Office**.
>
> If the computer is not online at the time
>   you specified to check for updates, then the Windows Update client
>   begins checking every five hours until it successfully finds updates.
>
> If more than 30 days have gone by without successfully finding
>   updates, the client will notify you. If you should receive such a
>   notification, you should connect your computer to the Internet, go to
>   the Windows Update Web site, and check for updates.